# Objects types in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

This is a fairly general question coming from a newbie in the learning phase and is on something I need clarifying.

I'm currently learning about objects and at this point I'm learning about inheritance. At this point in the lesson I've learned a few different ways to create objects but objects using the `this` keyword seems to have the most function:

```
function Person(){
    this.eyes = 2;
    this.ears = 2;
    this.arms = 2;
    this.hands = 2;
    this.feet = 2;
    this.legs = 2;
    this.species = "Homo sapien";
    }
```

I understand what I might use this for but then there's an object created this way:

```
var person = new Object();
person.eyes = 2;
person.ears = 2;
person.arms = 2;
person.hands = 2;
person.feet = 2;
person.legs = 2;
person.species = "Homo sapien";
```

Because I seem to be able to do things with the former that I can't do with the latter, I'm wondering if there's any reason why I wouldn't just use the former method all the time. Can anyone help me out with this? I don't need a long detailed answer (although one would be appreciated). It's just a question I want to get out of my head so that I don't dwell on it.

Comment: *"Because I seem to be able to do things with the former that I can't do with the latter"* Like what? The only thing that comes to mind (granted, it's a biggie) is associate prototype properties with instances.

Comment: Notice, that `Person` is not an object, it's a constructor function. To get an object, you've to call that constructor with `new` operator.

Comment: I would never recommend using `new Object()`, for this functionality write a literal `{}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Preface**: If you're not sure what I mean by the word "prototype" below, skip down to below the divider for an explanation, then come back up here to the top of the answer. :-)

---

Assuming in your first example that you then call `Person` via `new`:

```
var person = new Person();
```

...then the only difference between that `person` and the one you'd get using your second example is related to inheritance: The one created via `new Person` gets assigned the object on `Person.prototype` as its underlying prototype.

> I'm wondering if there's any reason why I wouldn't just use the former method all the time

If you don't need to use the prototype, then using a constructor function could be unnecessarily complicated. Note that your second form could more concisely be written:

```
var person = {
    eyes: 2,
    ears: 2,
    arms: 2,
    hands: 2,
    feet: 2,
    legs: 2,
    species: "Homo sapien"
};
```

That's called an *object initializer*: It creates a new object with the properties you see listed. There's never any need to use `x = new Object()`; if you want a new, blank object, just use `x = {};`.

When an object is a one-off, creating it directly is often the simplest way to create it.

The key advantage constructor functions have is that they're factories for objects that are fundamentally similar: Have the same set of initial properties, have the same underlying prototype, etc. And the function can accept arguments and use them to outfit the object it's creating in an appropriate way, perhaps do some validation on the construction arguments, etc. That is: They centralize initialization logic.

Constructor functions are not the only way to have function factories. You can also do:

```
function buildPerson() {
    return {
        eyes: 2,
        ears: 2,
        arms: 2,
        hands: 2,
        feet: 2,
        legs: 2,
        species: "Homo sapien"
    };
}
var person = buildPerson();
```

And if you want that person to have a prototype (ES5 browsers and higher):

```
var personPrototype = {
    // ...properties for the person prototype...
};
function buildPerson() {
    var obj = Object.create(personPrototype);
    obj.eyes = 2;
    obj.ears = 2;
    obj.arms = 2;
    obj.hands = 2;
    obj.feet = 2;
    obj.legs = 2;
    obj.species = "Homo sapien";
    return obj;
}
var person = buildPerson();
```

(There's another, more verbose way to define those properties as well.)

JavaScript is amazingly flexible. :-)

---

#### "Prototype"

JavaScript uses *prototypical inheritance*, which is a fancy way of saying that a object A can be "backed" by object B so that if you ask A for a property it doesn't have, the JavaScript engine will look to see if that property exists on B. A quick practical example:

```
var proto = {
    name: "proto's name"
};
var obj = Object.create(proto); // Creates an object backed by the given prototype
```

Don't worry about `Object.create`, for now all you need to know is that it creates a new object and assigns its underlying prototype based on the object you pass into it. So `obj` is backed by `proto`.

`obj` doesn't have a `name` property, but if we do:

```
console.log(obj.name);
```

...we see `"proto's name"`. That's because when the JavaScript engine tried to get `name`'s value from `obj`, it found that `obj` didn't have a `name` property, so it looked to `obj`'s prototype, `proto`. Having found it there, it used the value from `proto`.

That only happens when *getting* the value (except in some advanced cases we can ignore for now). When *setting* a property's value, it gets set on the object you set it on. So:

```
var proto = {
    name: "proto's name"
};
var obj = Object.create(proto); // `obj` is backed by `proto`
console.log(obj.name);          // "proto's name"
obj.name = "obj's name";
console.log(obj.name);          // "obj's name"
```

The purpose of prototypes is *reuse*, and so it's no surprise that an object can be the prototype of several other objects:

```
var proto = {
    name: "proto's name"
};
var a = Object.create(proto);   // `a` is backed by `proto`
var b = Object.create(proto);   // `b` is also backed by `proto`
console.log(a.name);            // "proto's name"
console.log(b.name);            // "proto's name"
a.name = "a's name";
console.log(a.name);            // "a's name"
console.log(b.name);            // "proto's name"
```

Prototype objects are normal objects; we can change them:

```
var proto = {
    name: "proto's name"
};
var obj = Object.create(proto);
console.log(obj.name);          // "proto's name"
proto.name = "updated";
console.log(obj.name);          // "updated"
```

Since `obj` doesn't have its own `name` property, each time we access it, the JavaScript engine goes and looks at its prototype.

The `new` operator *automatically* assign a prototype to the objects it creates: It uses the object that the function's `prototype` property has on it. So:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("My name is " + this.name);
};
var p = new Person("Fred"); // Creates an object backed by Person.prototype,
                            // then calls Person with this referring to the
                            // object
p.sayName();                // "My name is Fred";
```

Finally: Since prototype objects are normal objects, they also can have prototypes:

```
var rootProto = {
    name: "root proto's name"
};
var middleProto = Object.create(rootProto);
middleProto.middleProp = "middle property";
var obj = Object.create(middleProto);
console.log(obj.name);       // "root proto's name"
console.log(obj.middleProp); // "middle property"
```

For `name`, the JavaScript engine looks at `obj`, doesn't see a `name` property, and so looks at `middleProto`. It doesn't see a `name` property there, either, so it looks at `rootProto`. It finds it there, so it uses it.

Point of confusion: A lot of people are confused by the fact that the property on constructor functions is called `prototype` and think that somehow it's the prototype of the function. It isn't. It's just a normal property on function objects (functions are objects and can have properties). The **only** way it's special is that `new` uses it when you call the function via `new`. Non-function objects don't have a `prototype` property, they're prototype isn't a normal property, it's an internal thing. You can get an object's prototype by passing it into `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```
var proto = {/*...*/};
var obj = Object.create(proto);
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === proto; // true
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. On one note, I'd like to add that these examples were copied right out of the text I'm reading and I wondered myself about why it flip-flops between using this method (x = new Object();) and this method (x={ };). At any rate, you did a good job explaining why I'd want to use one method over the other and that's what I was looking for in an answer.

Comment: @AGx-07_162: Your wondering about that is a very good sign for your future in JavaScript. :-)